# Мультизагрузка и загрузчики

Tags: dual-boot

Пользователь решил сделать мультизагрузку и установил себе на жесткий диск сначала ОС Windows, затем две одинаковых ОС Linux (все ОС в разные разделы).

Сколько загрузчиков будет в такой системе?

Приведите ответ в свободной форме со своим комментарием.

Помогите, пожалуйста, не могу разобраться с вопросом.

Comment: От нуля до бесконечности в зависимости от конкретных действий пользователя.

Comment: Ну и ещё в зависимости от того, что конкретно автор вопроса подразумевает под термином «загрузчик» (как интерпретировать multi-stage, EFISTUB и в целом EFI-приложения?)